# Setting up build command to get the runtime of C++ program in Geany

Tags: c++, ubuntu, geany

Is there any way that I can see the run time of my C++ program in Geany? I am trying to add a execute command like this  `"time(./%e<i.txt)"` it is giving error
`./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: time(./g<i.txt): not found`
I have i.txt in the same directory as output file.I just want to know the runtime of my C++ programs while taking input from .txt file without writing the commands every time in the terminal myself any way I can do this?

Comment: Maybe you want the [`time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command?

Comment: i am aware of time command.i want to use time command in script of the editor so that when  i execute the program along with output i should get runtime of program without explicitly typing each and every time in terminal

Comment: Then use it *properly*, e.g. `time ./%e < i.txt`

Comment: functionality of both time() and time is same i used that also but same result.

Comment: Please try to configure it like that: Set run command in terminal and activate "don't use run script". Both option are located inside settings->Terminal. At least for a fast try here with a Python script it worked.